# JQuery-Get value from select option to use in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to generate a query that contains the value selected from a drop down menu the value would be saved into a PHP variable

```js
<script>
$(document).ready( function ()
{
  /* we are assigning change event handler for select box */
 /* it will run when selectbox options are changed */
 $('#dropdown_selector').change(function()
 {
  /* setting currently changed option value to option variable */
  var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  /* setting input box value to selected option value */
  $('$showoption').val(option);
 });
});
</script>
```

```html
<?
mysql_query("Select unit_price From products where id= '" . $id_value . "'");
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qquery)){
           $unit = $row['unit_price'];
          }
?>

<select class="form-control" name="model" id="dropdown_selector" >
<option value="1">1001</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Consider putting it in a form and then submit that form or use a backend call to another php file with the query-stuff

Comment: check out $.ajax or document.formname.submit();

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to get the value of the select and submit it using a form on the same page. Then you can access the GET/POST parameters in PHP.

Another option could be to get the value of the select on change and make a request to a php page which does what you want with that data. It can also return back any data you want too.